# C# simple program error. Cannot get console to process my else statement request

Tags: c#

I've used Try.Parse to make sure the program picks up only integers. When i type in an integer it works and goes on to the next part of my program, but when i type in a decimal, it takes the program to the else statement like it should, where it says decimals aren't valid and asks for an integer. So when i run the program and type in the integer, it just keeps asking for more and more integers and doesn't take in that I've just typed in an integer. So after typing in a decimal, it takes me there. I then type in an integer and it keeps replaying my request for another integer.

I've just started coding so forgive me if this is extremely basic but i cannot wrap my head around it. I want the computer to take in and process that I've typed in an integer and move on to the next statement.

An explanation would be really helpful! thank you in advance.

Comment: `inputcost` never changes.

Comment: OK, you're calling int.TryParse() twice in a row with the same parameters. The first time, you save the return value as `result`. Then you call it as the condition of a `while`. If `result` is false, the body of the while will *never be executed, not ever*. The only other place you check for `result` being false is inside the while loop, which you made sure can't happen in that case.

Comment: Also you can write `if (result)` instead of `if (result == true)`.

Answer (score 3):

you need to update `result` and `inputcost` inside the loop

```
while (!result)
{
       Console.Write("Please Enter A Valid Integer Value");
       Console.WriteLine();
       inputcost = Console.ReadLine();
       result = int.TryParse(inputcost, out validcost);

 }

 Console.Write("Valid Value");
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of inputcost is only set once in your code. You need to update it in your while loop.

See the false clause in the while loop:

static void Main(string[] args)
    {

```
    string inputcost;
    string inputmoney;
    int validcost;

    Console.Write("Please Enter The Cost, In Pennies, Of The Item You Have Purchased: ");
    inputcost = Console.ReadLine();

    bool result = int.TryParse(inputcost, out validcost);
    while (!int.TryParse(inputcost, out validcost))
    {
        if (result == true)
        {
            Console.Write("Valid Value");
        }
        if (result == false)
        {
            Console.Write("Please Enter A Valid Integer Value");
            Console.WriteLine();
            inputcost = Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
```

Comment: How many times do you think that `while` loop block is going to execute if `result` is false?